# MYSQL how select results where date fields are different by two years

Tags: mysql, date, operators

I have two columns where one is date_created and one is date_expired. How can i get the results where the difference is 2 years+? We know that each cert is good for 2 years only.

This example shows that the certificate expired already

```
SELECT date_created, date_expired from cert_table
```

Results:

```
2013-10-10 18:32:54, 2015-10-10 14:33:28
```

Comment: You could have a try with a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date_created, date_expired 
FROM  cert_table
WHERE DATE_ADD(date_created, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) <= date_expired
```

or I guess

```
SELECT date_created, date_expired 
FROM  cert_table
WHERE DATE_ADD(date_created, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) <= NOW()
```

**UPDATE** So if you switched `<=` to `>=` that means you were searcing for **valid** certificate instead of my queries above looking for expired ones. :-)

```
SELECT date_created, date_expired 
FROM  cert_table
WHERE DATE_ADD(date_created, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) >= date_expired
```

Comment: This one worked

SELECT date_created, date_expired 
FROM  cert_table
WHERE DATE_ADD(date_created, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) <= NOW()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datatype of your columns is date (which it *really* should be!), the following will do the job:

```
SELECT ... FROM cert_table WHERE DATE_ADD(date_created, INTERVAL 2 YEAR)  < date_expired
```

To get more information about date manipulations, have a look at the [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)